# hibernate criteria.setResultTransformer() with projections.distinct (composite foreign keys)

Tags: hibernate, distinct

I have SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT archiveSer, clas, classifdegree
FROM realization_archive
WHERE realId = 2
ORDER BY archiveSer DESC
```

My tables are mapped in hibernate as follows:

main table (realization_archive):

```
public class RealizationArchive implements Serializable {
@Id
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Column(name = "archiveSer", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long archiveSerial;

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "realId", referencedColumnName = "realId", nullable = false)
private CreditRealization creditRealization;

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "classif", referencedColumnName = "classif"), @JoinColumn(name = "classifdegree", referencedColumnName = "classifdegree") })
private ClassificationDegree classification;

...
}
```

object which is composite foreign key in main table RealizationArchive (realization_archive)

```
public class ClassificationDegree implements Serializable{
@Id
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "classif", referencedColumnName = "clas", nullable = false)
private ClassificationLevel classificationLevel;

@Column(name = "classifdegree")
private Integer classificationDegree;
...
}
```

simple foregin key in ClassificationDegeree

```
public class ClassificationLevel implements Serializable {
@Id
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Column(name = "clas", nullable = false)
private Integer classificationLevelId;

...
}
```

simple foreign key in RealizationArchive

```
public class CreditRealization implements Serializable{
@Id
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
@Column(name = "realId", nullable = false)
private Long creditRealizationId;
...
}
```

I am trying to do previously mentioned SQL query with criteria like this:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(RealizationArchive.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("creditRealization.creditRealizationId", creditRealizationId));
        criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("archiveSerial"));
        criteria.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("creditRealization").as("creditRealization"))
                .add(Projections.property("archiveSerial").as("archiveSerial"))
                .add(Projections.property("classification").as("classification"))));
        criteria.setMaxResults(1);

        criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(RealizationArchive.class));
        return criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

BUT, my problem is that in the object that is returned (RealizationArchive) values for fields 
    RealizationArchive.classification.classificationDegree 
and
    RealizationArchive.classification.classificationLevel.classificationLevelId
are not loaded properly. (they have null values, but in the db they are e.g 0, 1).
It works for simple foreign key (e.g for creditRealization [realId]), but when I have composite foreign key (e.g for classification [classif, classifdegree]) values are not loaded ... Bottom line, my SQL query generates just fine (syntactically), BUT returning object has all values set corectlly, EXCEPT those one that are part of the composite foreign key (that is, classificationLevelId(db name - clas) and classificationDegree (db name - clasifdegree)) ...

Can this be done by criteria and if so, how? I don't get it, what am I doing wrong?
Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks in advance for your time and patience :)

mismas

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using projections, since what you want to load is an entity instance? And why use Criteria for such a query, which doesn't need to be compose dynamically.

Here's the corresponding HQL:

```
select r from RealizationArchive r 
where r.creditRealization.creditRealizationId = :creditRealizationId 
order by r.archiveSerial desc
```

If you really want to make your life difficult, and use criteria for this, you just need this:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(RealizationArchive.class, "r");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("r.creditRealization.creditRealizationId", creditRealizationId);
c.addOrder(Order.desc("r.archiveSerial"))
```

Your code would be more readable and concise if you just named your ID properties `id`. Naming the ID of CreditRealization `creditRealizationId` is redundant.

Comment: Query will be populated dinamically, but to simplify things (as I hoped so, but obviously got myself misunderstood) I put realId = 2. It isn't part with creditRealizationId which bothers me, but the part with composite foreign key (classification) for which values (classificationLevelId, classificationDegree) are not being loaded.

Comment: Have you got any other suggestions? Why hibernate does not load those values (classificationLevelId, classificationDegree), but does it prefectly well with creditRealizationId? I suppose it matters the fact that one is simple foreign key (consists of one column) and the other is composite foreign key (consists of two columns)? Does hibernate have known issues with composite foreign keys? Can I solve it with criteria (which i preffer better than HQL) or it can be only done with HQL? (If so, why?)